# Android - Can we prevent activity start through ADB Shell?

Tags: android, adb

I want to prevent application activity from starting through ADB shell using below command.

```
am start -n com.xyz.namespace/com.xyz.namespace.AbcActivity
```

I have tried with setting `android:exported = false` and setting custom permissions in AndroidManifest file, both solutions doesn't works for me.

Is there any other way to prevent activity start through ADB Shell?

Answer (score 0):

If adb is running with root privileges no thing can stop it.
Try to use command adb unroot
Then try it again and you will find that it Will not work
Also if the targeted activity is the main activity any application can start it because it's exported by intent filters